# Auto building an output list of possible words from OCR'ing errors based on a given population of words

Tags: mysql, perl, ocr, fuzzy-search

I wonder if in Perl/MySQL if is possible to build a list of variant words, based on a given word, to which that word may have the common OCR errors occurring (i.e. 8 instead of b)?  In other words, if I have a list of words, and in that list is the word "Alphabet", then is there a way to extend or build a new list to include my original word plus the OCR error variants of "Alphabet"?  So in my output, I could have the following variants to Alphabet perhaps:

```
Alphabet
A1phabet
Alpha8et
A1pha8et
```

Of course it would be useful to code for most if not all of the common errros that appear in OCR'ed text.  Things like 8 instead of b, or 1 instead of l.  I'm not looking to fix the errors, because in my data itself I could have OCR errors, but want to create a variant list of words as my output based on a list of words I give it as an input.  So in my data, I may have Alpha8et, but if I do a simple search for Alphabet, it won't find this obvious error.

My quick and dirty MySQL approach

```
Select * from   
(SELECT Word
FROM words
union all
-- Rule 1 (8 instead of b)
SELECT 
case
    when Word regexp 'b|B' = 1 
        then replace(replace(Word, 'B','8'),'b','8')
    end as Word
FROM words
union all
-- Rule 2 (1 instead of l)
SELECT 
case
    when Word regexp 'l|L' = 1 
        then replace(replace(Word, 'L','1'),'l','1')
    end as Word
FROM words) qry
where qry.Word is not null
order by qry.Word;
```

I'm thinking there must be a more automated and cleaner method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have examples of scanned texts with both the as-scanned (raw) version, and the corrected version, it should be relatively simple to generate a list of the character corrections.  Gather this data from enough texts, then sort it by frequency.  Decide how frequent a correction has to be for it to be "common," then leave only the common corrections in the list.

Turn the list into a map keyed by the correct letter; the value being an array of the common mis-scans for that letter.  Use a recursive function to take a word and generate all of its variations.

This example, in Ruby, shows the recursive function.  Gathering up the possible mis-scans is up to you:

```
VARIATIONS = {
  'l' => ['1'],
  'b' => ['8'],
}

def variations(word)
  return [''] if word.empty?
  first_character = word[0..0]
  remainder = word[1..-1]
  possible_first_characters =
    [first_character] | VARIATIONS.fetch(first_character, [])
  possible_remainders = variations(remainder)
  possible_first_characters.product(possible_remainders).map(&:join)
end

p variations('Alphabet')
# => ["Alphabet", "Alpha8et", "A1phabet", "A1pha8et"]
```

The original word is included in the list of variations.  If you want *only* possible mis-scans, then remove the original word:

```
def misscans(word)
  variations(word) - [word]
end

p misscans('Alphabet') 
# => ["Alpha8et", "A1phabet", "A1pha8et"]
```

---

A quick-and-dirty (and untested) version of a command-line program would couple the above functions with this "main" function:

```
input_path, output_path = ARGV
File.open(input_path, 'r') do |infile|
  File.open(output_path, 'w') do |outfile|
    while word = infile.gets
      outfile.puts misscans(word)  
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The Ruby solution looks interesting. On the p variations ('Alphabet') statement, is there a way to change it so that it takes in a word from say "words.txt" (each word on a line) and then output these variations to a file (again one word per line)?  My thoughts would be from the command line do something like this "ruby variations.rb words.txt" perhaps

Comment: @user1236443, I've added an example of a main loop to do that.

Comment: Does the main loop come before or after the def variations?

Comment: @user1236443, It comes after.

Comment: And what is the correct command line syntax?  I seem to get a few errors "Variations.rb:22:in `initialize': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)"  I'm running it as ruby variations.rb words.txt.  In words.txt I simply have my word "Alphabet".  Does the loop above process a line by line?

Comment: @user1236443, I'm afraid the program has just clobbered your words.txt file.  This program does not read the variations from a file: It expects them to be hard coded into the VARIATIONS hash.  The first argument is the input file; the second is the file into which the input variations should be written.  I apologize for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to read the contents of words.txt (which are my words) line by line and feed ito into the program so that each word is applied to the def variations code in order ot output a list to another file.  The VARIATIONS has is good, because I can simply add new variations.

Comment: @user1236443, let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21018/discussion-between-wayne-conrad-and-user1236443)

Comment: Thanks Wayne.  You need to change the outfile.puts misscans(word) to outfile.puts variations(word) and it then works brilliantly by running it as ruby variations.rb words.txt words2.txt

Comment: I'm definitetly coming around to the Ruby way of doing things :-)

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way for achieving this is by using the [bitap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitap). Perl has [re::engine::TRE](https://metacpan.org/module/re%3a%3aengine%3a%3aTRE), a binding to [libtre](http://laurikari.net/tre/about/) which implements the fuzzy string matching in regexp:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);
use re::engine::TRE max_cost => 1;

# match "Perl"
if ("A pearl is a hard object produced..." =~ /\(Perl\)/i) {
    say $1; # find "pearl"
}
```

Plus, there is [agrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep) tool which allows you to use libtre from the command line:

```
$ agrep -i -E 1 peArl *
fork.pl:#!/usr/bin/env perl
geo.pl:#!/usr/bin/env perl
leak.pl:#!/usr/local/bin/perl
```

When you need to match several words against the OCRized text, there are two distinct approaches.

You could simply build one regexp with your entire dictionary, if it is small enough:

```
/(Arakanese|Nelumbium|additionary|archarios|corbeil|golee|layer|reinstill\)/
```

Large dictionary queries can be optimized by building trigram index.
Perl has a [String::Trigram](https://metacpan.org/module/String%3a%3aTrigram) for doing this in-memory.
Several RDBMS also have trigram index extensions. PostgreSQL-flavored [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) allows you to write queries like this, which are fast enough even for really big dictionaries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT street, similarity(street, word)
    FROM address_street
    JOIN (
        SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['higienopolis','lapa','morumbi']) AS word
    ) AS t0 ON street % word;
```

(this one took ~70ms on a table with ~150K rows)

Comment: What if I had a text file containing 255 words and want Perl to output this into a separate file?

Comment: You can read your "dictionary" and build a single regular expression matching all the words, like `/\(alphabet|test|word|whatever\)/i`